# Bounding below the difference of sums

Tags: analysis, algorithms, logarithms

I would like to bound below the following expression:

$\lambda(m,n)=\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{m+n}\lg{i} - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{m}\lg{i} - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n}\lg{i}$

by some expression that ideally uses logarithms of $m$ and $n$. Note that $m \leq n$.

My first attempt was to use the integral of logarithms. However, since we have a difference of sums, we cannot simply change the sums for integrals as the difference will be smaller, thus yielding a greater result. What is a usual strategy to bound logarithmic sums? I also tried changing the bounds, hence reducing the expression to two terms which is still a difference of sums.

Any hint about solving this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Stirling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) is a good way to deal with such sums.

Comment: That is just $\log \binom{m + n}{m}$, bounds on that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what exactly you want, but I'll let you do what is better and I'll just show you another form to write this. Maybe my answer is somehow useful (let me know in the comments if that's not the case). I don't know what $\lg (i)$ is, so I'll use whatever base $a>1$. Note that $$\log_{a}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{m+n}k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{m+n}\log_{a}(k).$$ With that, we can write $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m+n}\log_{a}{i}-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}\log_{a}{i}-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\log_{a}{i}\\=\log_{a}{\left(\prod_{i=1}^{m+n}i\right)}-\log_{a}{\left(\prod_{i=1}^{m}i\right)}-\log_{a}{\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}i\right)}=\log_{a}(m+n)!-\log_{a}(m)!-\log_{a}(n)!=\log_{a}\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}.$$ This is a nicer form, but we can go further. Note that $\binom{m+n}{m}=\frac{(m+n)!}{m!(m+n-m)!}=\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}$ and then your original function $$\lambda(m,\,n)=\log_{a}{m+n\choose m}$$ which, for some weird reason, $\LaTeX$ is refusing to render nicely. In that form, you just need to make two operations. First, compute $t={m+n \choose m}$. Second, compute $\log_{a}t$. To get upper, lower bounds and approximations, you can use several techniques. A variation of Stirling's approximation uses $$\sqrt{2\pi}\,n^{n+1/2}\lt n! \lt e\sqrt{2\pi}\,n^{n+1/2},$$ which I think that is a good lower bound. Does this fit the bill to you?